# How to print struct as a plain string with escape characters in golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to print a Golang struct as a string with escape characters, but not able to do that.

I want to print my struct like this:

`"{\"data\":\"MyName\",\"value\":\"Ashutosh\"}"`

Here is what I have tried.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Resp struct {
    Data  string `json:"data"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func main() {

    var data Resp
    data.Data = "Name"
    data.Value = "Ashutosh"

    r, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    fmt.Println("MyStruct: ", string(r))

}
```

But it is printing like this.

`{"data":"Name","value":"Ashutosh"}`

Can someone help me to get the following output? :

`"{\"data\":\"MyName\",\"value\":\"Ashutosh\"}"`

Comment: Use `strconv.Quote()` like this: `fmt.Println("MyStruct:", strconv.Quote(string(r)))`, or use the `%q` verb: `fmt.Printf("MyStruct: %q", r)`. Try it here: https://go.dev/play/p/8t4Tw0RRJhi

Comment: What's your purpose to do that?

Comment: thanks @icza it worked. you can submit this as an answer. I will mark it as a proper solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @amikai In my organization, some partners need our data in that form. I was earlier formatting the string manually and it was laborious. As I am new to Golang I didn't know this. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote any strings, you may use [`strconv.Quote()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Quote):

```
fmt.Println("MyStruct:", strconv.Quote(string(r)))
```

There's also a verb for quoting strings in the [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) package: `%q`:

> String and slice of bytes (treated equivalently with these verbs):
>
> ```
> %q    a double-quoted string safely escaped with Go syntax
> ```

So you may also print it like this:

```
fmt.Printf("MyStruct: %q", string(r))
```

Since this also works for byte slices, you don't even need the `string` conversion:

```
fmt.Printf("MyStruct: %q", r)
```

These all output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8t4Tw0RRJhi)):

```
MyStruct: "{\"data\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"Ashutosh\"}"
```